# BERT each Word Embedding in Keras

Tags: nlp, bert

How to use BERT to extract the embeddings of every word in a sentence.
Suppose I pass my corpus of sentences with different lengths to a BERT model , I want to be able to extract the embeddings of each word in every sentence.

And what is the best way to utilize every word embeddings? should I calculate their average?

when I follow the basic usage in this [BERT model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2/2), the sequence length is always 128 regardless of the actual sentence length, I know I can change the 128 but it will be the same for all sentences. Is there a way to get an embedding for every word and when the sentence length is less than 128 then remaining embeddings appear as zeros, for example, if my sentence is 7 words, I want bert to return an embeddings of (128,128) but the useful ones are the first 7 and the remaining are zeros.

Comment: I don't know if it helps: here is a cool tool for embeddings https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service

Comment: Thanks but that tool gives an embedding vector for sentences not words.